# How to get hits word in lucene.net

Tags: lucene.net

When searching with wildcard queries (dir*), how can I get the word that the query matched? The original content is stored within the document.

Answer (score 0):

You could analyze the stored content and pass it through the analyzer used in indexing to find out which tokens it generated, and then check if these match the query. You would then need to query the [IOffsetAttribute](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/interface_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_tokenattributes_1_1_i_offset_attribute.html) to find where in the original content the token originated.

Remember that the actual indexed token could be mangled by an analyzer as a step in stemming, it could also be a synonym, or just pure magic.

What you describe is often a step in trying to present highlighted search results. If so, there's already a [Lucene.Net.Search.Highlight](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/dc/dd1/namespace_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_highlight.html) package, a part of contrib.